# Fatal error on Windows XP when compiled with XP Targeting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm using TR2's filesystem library to retrieve the last modified time of a file with the `last_write_time` function however a fatal error occurs on Windows XP when `last_write_time` is called.

I'm unable to isolate the code that's causing a fatal error on Windows XP but not on Windows 7/8/10.

#### DLL project(fatal error)

- [CheckRevision.cpp](https://bpaste.net/show/6726339d3895)
- [CheckRevision.h](https://bpaste.net/show/ed64c98a3243)
- [util.cpp](https://bpaste.net/show/1da3daa4b6b8)
- [util.h](https://bpaste.net/show/766e55081268)

Here's my attempt at isolating the problematic code with a EXE project which does not give a fatal error:
[main.cpp](https://bpaste.net/show/8aab086edd4b)

Here's the error:

> Exception: 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION) at 001B:07043EAC
>
> The instruction at '0x07043EAC' referenced memory at '0x00000000'.
>
> The memory could not be 'read'.

Comment: Microsoft have dropped the support for windows Xp.

Comment: @sanjay - But they still supply a compiler targeting XP. :-)

Comment: Visual Studio 15 also has a `<filesystem>` that is not TR2, but C++14. Might be something to test (I cannot, as I have no XP-machines left).

Comment: @Bo Persson Filesystem isn't part of C++14, it's expected to be in C++17 though

Comment: You could enable dump files on XP, and look at the error on your development machine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the TLS issue on XP and Server 2003?

http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=181