# Visual Studio 2015: building with the Windows XP toolset selected still results in "not a valid win32 application" error on XP

Tags: c++, windows-xp, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 supports building C++ programs for Windows XP. According to the article [*Configuring C++11 Programs for Windows XP*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), enabling this support is simply a matter of selecting the appropriate platform toolset in the project properties.

This does not work in my case. A simple "hello world" program written in C++ and compiled in Visual Studio Community 2015 (version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1) with the platform toolset set to `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)` and the platform set to x86/Win32 generates the generic "[name of executable] is not a valid Win32 application" error when run on a Windows XP computer.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I've found a number of questions about similar issues ([like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488549/targetting-windows-xp-from-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305633/xxxxxx-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434511/fatal-error-on-windows-xp-when-compiled-with-xp-targeting-in-visual-studio-2015)), but nothing helpful yet.

Comment: Did you want a Win32 app or a console app?

Comment: Just console for now (my current test program simply sends the string "Testing" to cout).

Comment: When you created the project did you select Win32 Console Application?

Comment: I selected "Empty Project" (although the resulting executable runs as a console application on Windows 7).

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Any advice?